# Unable to decrease the height as the text gets removed in a dynamic texarea

Tags: javascript, html, css, textarea, css-position

```
<div class="mainContainer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="footerCls">
    <div class="inputcls">
      <textarea name="text" placeholder="Text goes here..." onkeydown="expand(event,this)" onkeyup="expand(event,this)"></textarea>
      <div class="wc-commands" id="wc-commands">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="22px" height="22px" viewBox="0 0 22 22" version="1.1">
          <g stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
            <g transform="translate(-263.000000, -18.000000)">
              <g>
                <g transform="translate(264.000000, 19.000000)">
                  <path d="M7.09,7 C7.57543688,5.62004444 8.98538362,4.79140632 10.4271763,5.0387121 C11.868969,5.28601788 12.9221794,6.53715293 12.92,8 C12.92,10 9.92,11 9.92,11" id="Shape" stroke="#D2D2D2" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></path>
                  <circle id="Oval-2" fill="#D2D2D2" cx="10" cy="15" r="1"></circle>
                  <circle id="Oval" stroke="#D2D2D2" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" cx="10" cy="10" r="10"></circle>
                </g>
              </g>
            </g>
          </g>
        </svg>
      </div>
      <div class="wc-send" id="wc-send">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24px" height="20px" viewBox="0 0 24 20" version="1.1">
          <g stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
            <g transform="translate(-320.000000, -19.000000)" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="2">
              <g>
                <g transform="translate(321.000000, 20.000000)">
                  <polygon points="22 0 19 18 10 12 0 9"></polygon>
                  <path d="M9.5,11.5 L21.5,0.5"></path>
                  <polyline points="10 12 10 18 14 15"></polyline>
                </g>
              </g>
            </g>
          </g>
        </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  function expand(e, element) {
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    var element2 = document.getElementsByClassName("footerCls")[0];
    if (code != 13) {
      if (element.scrollHeight < 84) {
        element2.style.height = (element.scrollHeight) + "px";
        element.style.height = (element.scrollHeight) + "px";
        element.style.overflowY = "hidden";
      } else {
        element2.style.height = "125px";
        element.style.height = "84px";
        element.style.overflowY = "scroll";
      }
    } else {
      element2.style.height = "56px";
      element.style.height = "30px";
      element.value = "";
      element.style.overflowY = "hidden";
    }
  }

</script>
```

I've textarea where it increases as the text input gets added. It will reach a certain height(until 4 rows) and then scroll appears. I am unable to decrease the height when the text is removed.

Also, I am unable to set single line text by default.

<kbd>[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/wrwka2tk/16/)</kbd>

Below is the image which I am trying to achieve

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To achieve it in the most easy way you should make some small changes

1. Take off `position: absolute;` from `.inputcls` and `.inputcls textarea`. By doing this their wrapper will be adjusted automatically when the `textarea` change and you will not have to do it by code.
2. Instead of setting the `textarea` minimun height using pixels use the `rows` property to set the minimal number of rows that you want.

   ```
   <textarea rows="2"></textarea>
   ```
3. When the text changes set the height to `auto`. It will adjust the `textarea` height to the original height it should have. Then you can get its `scrollHeight` and set it again. So Actually your function should simply be:

   ```
   function expand(e, element) {
       element.style.height = "auto";

       if (element.scrollHeight <= 84) {
           element.style.height = element.scrollHeight + "px";
           element.style.overflowY = "hidden";
       } else {
           element.style.height = "84px";
           element.style.overflowY = "scroll";
       }
   }
   ```

See **[updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/okg5pv01/)**

**BTW**

You wrote:

> Also, I am unable to set single line text by default.

With this solution simply change `rows="2"` to `rows="1"`

**BTW2**

You dont need to use both `onkeydown` and `onkeyup`. Using only `onkeyup` would be better.

Comment: There is an issue here, height is not decreasing when we delete the text from 4th row to 3 row and so on until it reaches 1st row. It's coming to default only when the text is empty.

Comment: @Raviteja where are you experiencing this issue? In the fiddle? What browser are you testing it with? I have just tested it again in Chrome, FF, IE11, Edge and all of them seem to work fine (Decrease lines from 4 to 3 and 3 to 2 and so on...) [See this caption attached](https://anabolicdev.tinytake.com/sf/MjAxMzY0MF82MzU5OTg1) Isnt this the behavior you want?

Comment: Now it's working well. thanks. Also, Why not use both keydown and up?

Comment: Have a look at textarea https://docs.intercom.com/install-on-your-product-or-site/quick-install/install-intercom-on-your-web-app-for-logged-in-users here

Comment: @Raviteja you can use both but using them both to adjust the size is unnecessary because `onkeyup` will always follow `onkeydown`. Unnecessary events are always not a good practice. I put it in a comment at the end though since its just an advice. If you do have any reason you can always use both. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make below change :

```
<script>
  function expand(e, element) {
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    var element2 = document.getElementsByClassName("footerCls")[0];
    if (code != 13) {
      if (element.scrollHeight < 84) {
        element2.style.height = (element.scrollHeight) + "px";
        element.style.height = (element.scrollHeight) + "px";
        element.style.overflowY = "hidden";
      } else {
        element2.style.height = "125px";
        **element.style.height = "84px";**
        element.style.overflowY = "scroll";
      }
    } else {
      element2.style.height = "56px";
      element.style.height = "30px";
      element.value = "";
      element.style.overflowY = "hidden";
    }
  }

</script>
```

from :

```
element.style.height = "84px";
```

to

```
element.style.maxHeight = "84px";
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all you need to do is change the `min-height: 56px` on your `footerCls` class to something like for example: `min-height: 100px` seems to show more of the element.